# React Native: How to swipe something off screen with bounce?

Tags: animation, react-native

I'm trying to make something where you can swipe the overlay off the screen.

This is what I have so far using `PanResponder`, but I don't feel like it's very clean. It's my first time using it so I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this.

I need to animate the green part and more so I'd like to build this by hand if possible without using a package.

My component looks like this (heavily copied off this guy:
https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-animated-demo-tinder/blob/master/index.ios.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  PanResponder,
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
  },
  overlay: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#0000ff',
  },
  video: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: '#00ff00',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  }
});

function clamp(value, min, max) {
  return min < max
    ? (value < min ? min : value > max ? max : value)
    : (value < max ? max : value > min ? min : value)
}

export default class EdmundApp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,

      onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
        this.state.pan.setOffset({x: this.state.pan.x._value, y: 0});
        this.state.pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0});
      },

      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null, {dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: 0},
      ]),

      onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, vy}) => {
        this.state.pan.flattenOffset();
        if (vx >= 0) {
          velocity = clamp(vx, 3, 5);
        } else if (vx < 0) {
          velocity = clamp(vx * -1, 3, 5) * -1;
        }

        if (Math.abs(this.state.pan.x._value) > 150) {
          Animated.decay(this.state.pan, {
            velocity: {x: velocity, y: vy},
            deceleration: 0.98
          }).start()
        } else {
          Animated.spring(this.state.pan, {
            toValue: {x: 0, y: 0},
            friction: 4
          }).start()
        }
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    let { pan } = this.state;
    let translateX = pan.x;
    let swipeStyles = {transform: [{translateX}]};
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.video}></View>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.overlay, swipeStyles]} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('EdmundApp', () => EdmundApp);
```

[image]

Comment: if you have any doubt, please comment over here.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable

There is an option for bounce and exit which will help you for sure.

Comment: if i slide it less than half way will it go back to it's original position??

Comment: Please visit https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable/blob/master/definitions/sliding-exits.js and manage your sliding

Comment: and yes it would go back to it's original position

Comment: sorry would you mind giving me an example? i feel like the sliding one won't do what i need. i need to be able to swipe something off the screen, like in the demo

Comment: is it like swiping a card like tinder app?

Comment: just like in the demo above, i want to be able to swipe the blue part off the screen and eventually resize the green part so that it shrinks to the bottom right corner

Comment: please try this:-https://github.com/meteor-factory/react-native-tinder-swipe-cards/blob/master/SwipeCards.js  because its panresponder works similar to what you need.

Comment: that's what i'm doing now. and as you can see from the demo it is a bit choppy. sometimes the blue part is half on the screen

Comment: are you trying on android device?

Comment: iOS simulator for now

Comment: please try this on iOS device and merry Christmas.